# "Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type ((_) -> _)" only in init

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a computed property on an NSManagedObject subclass (for Core Data) to return an enum value:

```
class Group: NSManagedObject {

  enum SectionType {
    case systems
    case statuses
  }

  ...

  var section: SectionType {
    get {
      if (pages.count == 0) {
        return .statuses
      } else {
        return .systems
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In an init method for a data source, I'm trying to filter on this computed property, and getting the error "Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type ((_) -> _)'":

```
class FilterDataSource {

  init(results: [Group]) {

    let unsortedSystems = results.filter { $0.section == .systems }
    // "Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type ((_) -> _)'"
    ...
  }
}
```

If I try to filter with the same closure outside of init, no error:

```
func funcOutsideOfInit() {
  let testArr = [Group]()
  // no error for this:
  let unsortedSystems = testArr.filter { $0.section == .systems }
}
```

The array of objects I'm trying to filter is a passed parameter for the init, so it doesn't seem to me that it would have anything to do with it being in init.

I have also tried conforming the SectionType enum to Equatable explicitly, but still get the error.

Why am I only getting this error using filter with this closure in init?

Comment: Can't replicate it: http://swiftstub.com/197261717/?v=beta

Comment: You are not conforming the Group class to NSManagedObject, could that have something to do with it? Also, I'm using Xcode 6.4, thinking it may be a compiler issue...

Comment: Is that fixed if you add closure types explicitly? e.g. `{ (group: Group) => Bool in group.section == .systems}`.

Comment: That code compiles fine for me in both Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 beta 6.

Comment: @Sulthan yes, adding closure types explicitly fixes. Want to submit that as an answer so I can mark it? :)